# Where is the best position for company logo in services login page?

Tags: gui-design, layout, branding

I'm designing the UX and UI of a suite of products which are SaaS services. These products work just like Microsoft online services, or very similar to Google Apps for businesses. I'm stuck with the branding and positioning of both companies. One is the consumer of the service (which of course should be bolder and more apparent to the users), and one is the seller of the services. The logo of the seller should be there, because of marketing strategies.

Now, I'm confused about where to show and how to show logos of seller and consumer companies. Do we have any best practice for this?

Comment: You mean it's something like "{Company X} product in association with {Company Y}" sort of thing? i.e. one company licenses it for their own use, but the parent company need to still have their logo displayed as part of the licensing agreement?

Comment: How significant is to show the powering company's logo ? do they get revenue out of that

Comment: @JonW, exactly, both companies logos should be on the page. However, not like "x product in association with y". Maybe on different parts of the page.

Comment: @Mervin, it's important and significant. It's because this is a niche market (few sellers, few buyers), and it's very significant for the purpose of marketing.

Answer (score 2):

I am designing a SaaS web app that sounds very similar. I have put my company's customer branding logo in the upper left, and my company's logo in the lower left in the footer. This way my customer's branding is prominently displayed for their end users, but down below there is a subtle reminder as to who is really powering this software.

I think this is pretty standard practice on the web. Lots of major websites will brand the page all their own, but down in the footer reveal that they are built on Wordpress, or hosted by MediaTemple, etc.

Answer (score 0):

I really like the approach that some companies have employed, that is, adding a small label in the footer of the page. The label could be a small version of the logo, wrapped in some neatly layout-fitting background, and not outstanding too much from the general layout color palette.

Answer (score 0):

My thought is similar to Scott and DiH, although instead of on the left inside the footer, I think the right side in the footer might be better.

I only say this because I imagine viewing the copyright and date in the bottom left inside the footer and not necessarily a logo of some kind.